# Compiling From Command Line Wth Circular Dependencies

Tags: java, compilation

Imagine that I have two classes (shown below). Now imagine that I am compiling them using javac.exe from the command line.  They won't compile because class A needs class B's methods to exist and vice versa.  Is there any trick to getting them to compile from the command line?  (Eclipse can compile this no problems!)

I should add they are both currently in two separate .java files.

```
public class A {
    public void doAWork() { /* A work goes here. */}
    public void doBWork() { new B().doBWork(); }
}
public class B {
    public void doBWork() { /* B work goes here. */}
    public void doAWork() { new A().doAWork(); }
}
```

Comment: For me, compiling it in the following way works perfectly: `javac A.java  B.java`

Comment: You need to make sure both are available to be compiled at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your issue is elsewhere.

I can perfectly compile the code in Java 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7 with the following command:

```
javac A.java B.java
```

Even providing a single file name works perfectly, since B.java is in the same directory:

```
javac A.java
```

Are you sure the two files are placed in appropriate directories?

Comment: Um no, I hadn't tried that.  I will.  The problem actually appears in a much larger project with dozens of files I am compiling in a script one at a time.  A circular dependency popped up and before eliminating the CD I was wondering if there was a compiler trick to allow me to leave the CD in.  Clearly, yours is the way to do this from the command line.  Thanks again.

Comment: You can compile them one at a time on the command line???  Then I might be doing something wrong.  I will look deeper.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It led me in the right direction.  Because the command was being executed in a directory other than where the source files were, the source file directory needed to be added to the classpath argument of javac.exe.